# QGIS 3.16 - unpractical changes to intersect tool?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, intersection

I currently am testing QGIS 3.16. I just ran `intersect` without any input modifications on a buffer layer with 12 polygons (first input) and a layer with 417 administrative districts (second input). The expected result (as created using 3.10) was a single layer which contains the 12 polygons, split by the administrative districts into smaller polygons and with the attributes of the districts attached to the buffers. Instead I got 1000 layers after the tool ran for about 7 minutes, of which only 3 contain data. Those 3 each represent the parts of an administrative district which my buffers cover.

I skimmed the change logs for 3.14 and 3.16 but couldn't find any explanation of these changes. What did I miss?

/edit: So, `saga:intersect` does what I expected/need. I still would like to understand the changes.

Comment: Perhaps something in your profile is messing with the tool, check https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39823, https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/39917. Maybe try with a clean Profile

Comment: Found the issue: The input data contained some empty geometries. After removing these, the intersect worked flawless.